# Roaming mend on a single target

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

As a healing sorcerer you have the ability ***Roaming Mend***.
This ability has the following tooltip.

> Roaming Mend
>
> Activation: Instant
>
> Force: 50
>
> Cooldown: 15 seconds
>
> Range: 30m
>
> Places a mending Force on a friendly target that heals them for
>   3748-4329 health the next time they take damage. **After healing the
>   target, Roaming Mend travels to another friendly target within 20
>   meters.** Roaming Mend lasts up to 30 seconds on each target and travels
>   up to 3 times, healing up to 4 targets. Roaming Mend can only be
>   placed on one target at a time.

**My question is;** what if there is no friendly target within 20m?

- Will roaming mend stay on the same target dormant until it comes
  within reach of someone else?
- Will it simply bounce back to the same target and heal it again (and
  heal it 4x)?
- Will it just end? meaning it went to one target and then poof..done..

I'm asking this from a PvP perspective, if i put roaming mend on one person and then quickly leave the area, will roaming mend be useful for that one person.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested this out, and it turns out that if the player with Roaming Mend applied to them takes damage while no other friendly is within 20 meters, it will heal them once and then disappear.  3 stacks of Roaming Mend Charges will remain on the healer who applied it, but they won't do anything even if the healer comes back within range and takes damage themselves.

So essentially your third case.